# MRI: Muti-threading + yield to main thread not working

Tags: ruby, multithreading

When I run this code, I only see "Loop 1" output once, and then just a constant stream of "Loop 2", "Loop 2"...

It's like the other loop is waiting on something and ends up blocked forever.

Any suggestions as to why?

```
def loop1(&block)
  loop do
    block.call("Loop 1")
    sleep 1
  end
end

def loop2(&block)
  loop do
    block.call("Loop 2")
    sleep 1
  end
end

def both(&block)
  Thread.new { loop1(&block) }
  loop2(&block)
end

both(&method(:puts))
```

I'm not even sure if it's the `puts` or the `block.call()` that causes the threaded loop to stop.

Comment: What version of Ruby? I don’t see this in any of the versions I’ve tried.

Comment: I'm using 2.1.2. I'll try another version too.

Comment: You're right, 2.1.5 seems to work ok (then again, I also used a different environment, since that was outside of Docker and on Ubuntu instead of Gentoo).

Comment: 2.1.2 works ok for me (on a Mac). It could be something to do with the OS?

Comment: Actually, I just tried Ruby 2.1.5 on the same OS and that works fine. Must be something weird with the build of 2.1.2 I've got.